# DbConnectionBroker + MySQL multiple connection issue

Tags: mysql, jdbc, struts2

I have an application in Struts 2 which connects to the MySQL database & I am using `DBConnectionBroker` for DB pooling -

While performing select after insert operations I am facing strange issues as below -

1. I insert & select a record in a table (on primary key id) & receive a success message, 
   but the result is not displayed until a refresh is performed.
2. When I successfully update a record the current changes are not reflected instead the previous value is displayed.
3. Multiple refresh keeps displaying different values every time (i.e old as well as new changes)

Below is my logs.log file details created by `DBConnectionBroker`:

===============================================================================
Starting DbConnectionBroker Version 1.0.13:

dbDriver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

dbServer = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dev01?profileSQL=true

dbLogin = esmdev

log file = c:\DBlogs.log

minconnections = 1

maxconnections = 20

Total refresh interval = 1.0 days

logAppend = false

maxCheckoutSeconds = 60

debugLevel = 2

---

Wed Aug 21 20:45:51 IST 2013  Opening connection 0 com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@1ff5c98:

Wed Aug 21 20:45:52 IST 2013  Opening connection 1 com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@a6e0a9:

-----> Connections Exhausted!  Will wait and try again in loop 1

================================================================================

My initial debugging/analysis by setting profileSQL=true on my dburl shows following logs in my eclipse ide console

===============================================================================
duration: 1 ms, ***connection-id: 29***, statement-id: 14, resultset-id: 16

duration: 2 ms, ***connection-id: 28***, statement-id: 15, resultset-id: 17

===============================================================================

The interesting part here I identified is connection-id - 
For same query I can see two different Ids (Min connection is 1) but result set is different.

I also observed one thing when I start tomcat in debug mode & set a breakpoint 
to watch few objects above it causes some delay/slows down the execution & only one connect-id is displayed & everything seems to work fine due to the delay.

I am confused as to why a new connection is created though I free the connection 
after queries are executed.

Comment: Without any code that does the actual work I don't see how to help.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have edited the earlier post by providing the code.

Comment: Just interesting what is the purpose of rummage the code about 15 years old, so catching the bugs or suffering of incompatibilities?

Comment: Yea I implemented other pooling technique.... cannot afford to waste time..Thank you all for your time :)